# Color overlay on drawable Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view, android-drawable

I've been following this tutorial here [Medium - Diagonal Cut View](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*IIPRX4i4cOAdxAMeGpY92w.png) to get that diagonal view effect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"  />

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/bebe"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:alpha="0.1" />
</item>

<item android:top="260dp"
    android:bottom="-100dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="-260dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-10"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

So far the code is the almost the same and the effect is achieved, but only works on Lollipop+, I have searched but cannot find how to have a color overlay on top of an drawable to achieve this same effect and all my tries has being in vain.

The drawable goes in the background property of a RelativeLayout. I have tried to make it in 2 separated ImageView, one for the background image and one for the color overlay, but that doesn't apply the diagonal style right.

How can one achieve this effect for  pre-lollipop versions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Drawable background = relativeLayout.getBackground();
background.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

you can also try `SRC_ATOP`or `MULTIPLY` depending on desired effect.

========= EDIT ========================

Ok, I think I now better understand what you are asking. It wasn't entirely clear at first.

You aren't asking about a color overlay per-say, or rather, that is not what your problem is. Your problem lies in your reliance on the alpha attribute.

Do this, I have reordered your elements, so that the colored shape goes on top of the image, and instead of making the image transparent, we make the colored shape's color have an specified alpha byte. You can change the color and alpha as you like.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/muse15fence_750"/>
    </item>
    
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#cc3F51B5"/>
        </shape>
    </item>



    <item
        android:bottom="-100dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="-260dp"
        android:top="260dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-10"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="100%">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid
                    android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This is what it looks like in Jelly Bean.

[image: Tested Example]

Comment: I have tried your solution, while the color overlay effect is applied, it turns out it the white diagonal cut also gets colored and everything looks like a giant colorAccent rectangle

Comment: @IvanAlberto I have updated your answer. I have tested it, and it will work. Just replace my image and color with your image and color.

Comment: Excellent! this was the effect that I was looking pre lollipop, interesting approach and quite flexible too! sadly I cannot upvote the answer, but thank you very much!