# how to make dynamic diagonal view list

Tags: android, android-layout

i m adding diagonal cut layout to `RecyclerView`, but i m not getting expected result. my second view `start with end of first view, and thats obvious`. but what i want is that each view is `join with each-other` like this.

**My Output:**

[image]

**and this is what i wanted:**

[image]

**CutLayout.class:**

```
public class CutLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private Xfermode pdMode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    private Path path = new Path();

    public CutLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CutLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CutLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CutLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        paint.setXfermode(pdMode);
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(0, getHeight());
        path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight());
        path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight() - TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
        paint.setXfermode(null);
    }
}
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".SampleActivity">

    <com.yarolegovich.slidingrootnav.sample.helper.CutLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <ImageView
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/homebulding" />
    </com.yarolegovich.slidingrootnav.sample.helper.CutLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185299/color-overlay-on-drawable-android

Comment: i've already seen it, thats not my problem.. what i want is combine dynamic view..

Comment: each link is already open in my browser.., i m also able to combine view statically. but how to dynamic?

Comment: [Create Diagonal Cut View in Android](https://medium.com/@adinugroho/create-diagonal-cut-view-in-android-5a376eca6a1c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `CutLayout` to have the same path on top like so:

```
public class CutLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private Xfermode pdMode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    private Path path = new Path();

    public CutLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CutLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CutLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CutLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        paint.setXfermode(pdMode);
        path.reset();

        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo(getWidth(), 0);
        path.lineTo(0, TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        path.reset();

        path.moveTo(0, getHeight());
        path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight());
        path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight() - TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
        paint.setXfermode(null);
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do is to create an item decorator for your Recycler view that can accept a negative top margin

```
public class NegativeTopItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration{
    private final int mTopMargin;

    public NegativeTopItemDecorator(int topMargin) {
        this.mTopMargin = topMargin;
    }


    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.top = mTopMargin;
    }
}
```

And add it to your RecyclerView

```
int topMargin = - (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
NegativeTopItemDecorator itemDecorator = new NegativeTopItemDecorator(topMargin);
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator);
```

This will give you something like the following output

[image: sample diagonal cut recycler]

Comment: In my case there is always white space at the end of card at bottom right. any idea how to solve this.

Comment: Have you applied the `NegativeTopItemDecorator`?

Comment: yes, thats why i get output like yours.. but at the last index image is also leave nagative space.